# Using INSERT with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

For a somewhat complex SQL script I need the following mapping:

```
WITH days_mapping AS (SELECT 1 AS day
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS day
UNION ALL
...
SELECT 31 AS day)
```

Is there any way to create the same mapping but without manually writing a SELECT and UNION ALL for every single number/day that should be in this mapping? I was thinking of doing an INSERT in a WHILE loop instead of the SELECT but I don't know how or if it is even possible to do that with common table expressions.

Comment: use a tally table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with days_mapping as (
      select 1 as day
      union all
      select day + 1
      from days_mapping
      where day < 31
     )
select *
from days_mapping;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=166241ba1889b89e86e1416715e36208) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  If you have more than 100 rows being generating, you need to use `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

Comment: Be aware that `option (maxrecursion 0)` can cause a infinite loop when the CTE is poorly written ..  **not in this case**, comment was meant as a general warning...

Comment: Why a rCTe and not a Tally Gordon? With 31 rows it's much of a muchness, but many more and the performance really degrades. Rather than recommending `option (maxrecursion 0)` you should be recommending a Tally.